# ifelse conditional statement based on the value before and after a particular element

Tags: r, conditional-statements

How can I create a conditional statement using `ifelse()` based on the value of a previous or following element in a vector in R?

```
data ≤– c(NA, NA, 3, NA, 4, 6, 7, 9, NA)
ifelse(conditional statement, NA, data)
```

Where the conditional statement is: if the elements on either side are *both* NA, then it should also be NA.  If it is a continuous series of numbers, they stay the same - unchanged.  The output should be

```
NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, 6, 7, 9, NA
```

I have tried `data[-1]==NA & data[+1]==NA` as the conditional statement but it converts everything to NA regardless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to use lead and lag functions in dplyr for this. First set your vector in a dataframe.

```
df <- data.frame(data  = data)
 
df %>%
    transmute(result = ifelse(is.na(lag(data)) & is.na(lead(data)), NA, data))
```

Comment: Also note you can't use x == NA to test for NA values.  The correct way is is.na(x).